# How to get the boundary vertices of a mesh under a special viewpoint? Just like the vertices on the silhouette lines

Tags: python

I would like to know how to get the boundary vertices of a mesh under the current viewpoint using the python script?

**hope：**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Just like the vertices on the silhouette lines.
[image]

How to get the boundary vertices of a mesh under a special viewpoint?
Just like the vertices on the silhouette lines.